# Emacs list of parent modes

Tags: emacs, elisp, mode

In emacs is it possible to get a list of parent modes for a derived mode?

I found derived-mode-p, but this only allows me to test if a mode is derived from another.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every [symbol has a property list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html#Symbol-Components) and for derived modes, this list includes the component `derived-mode-parent` which indicates which mode it was derived from.  It seems to be just a single symbol.

```
(define-derived-mode nst-mode text-mode "Testing")
=> nst-mode

(get 'nst-mode 'derived-mode-parent)
=> text-mode
```

I don't see how there could be more than one parent, ever.

Here is a demo of a transitive chain of parents.

```
(define-derived-mode rope nil "Victim of mouse")
(define-derived-mode mouse rope "Victim of cat")
(define-derived-mode cat mouse "Victim of dog")
(define-derived-mode dog cat "Enough already")

(let ((mode 'dog) parents)
  (while mode
    (setq parents (cons mode parents)
          mode (get mode 'derived-mode-parent)))
  (reverse parents))

=> (dog cat mouse rope)
```

... or, just for fun, a recursive version:

```
(defun derived-mode-parents (mode)
  (and mode
    (cons mode (derived-mode-parents
          (get mode 'derived-mode-parent)))))

(derived-mode-parents 'dog)
=> (dog cat mouse rope)
```

Comment: Even if a mode only can have one direct parent, that parent can have a parent of its own, which in turn can have a parent etc.

Comment: Oh yes, of course; just transitively follow the chain until you get one with an empty `derived-mode-parent` or lacking this property. Updated answer -- thanks for the comment!